# How do I get an array to place a zero on the first element and not skip it?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

The following code will place a 1 on list[0]:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    list[i] = i + 1;
```

if I just change

```
int i = 1
```

it will skip list[0] and place a 2 on list[1]

I want it like this:

```
list[0] = 0
list[1] = 1
list[2] = 2
```

Comment: set `list[0]` to **0** before entering the loop.

Comment: Use `list[i] = i ;` inside your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list[i] = i;
```

or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

just do this -

```
list[0]=0;
for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++){
    //set other things like -
    list[i]=i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is this `i3` comming from ?

You probably want:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
```